# VBA duplicate PDF file

Tags: vba

I really need help. I need a VBA function to make copies of a single PDF file. For example a file with the reference/name 1, I would need an amount x of copies lets say 1 to 10. In order to avoid coping and paste 9 times and renaming them manually I am sure there must be a function to do this job. I am very basic with VBA so any help would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need to add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime in the VBA editor. Then the following will work...

```
Public Sub Test()
    CopyFile "C:\Users\randrews\Desktop\1.gif", "C:\Users\randrews\Desktop", 10
End Sub

Public Sub CopyFile(OriginalPath As String, DestinationFolderPath, Copies As Integer)

Dim fs As New FileSystemObject

For i = 1 To Copies
    OrigName = fs.GetFileName(OriginalPath) 'file name with extention e.g. 1.gif
    OrigNumber = CInt(Left(OrigName, Len(OrigName) - 4)) 'file name converted to a number - this will crash if the file name contains any non numeric chars
    DestName = OrigNumber + i & "." & fs.GetExtensionName(OriginalPath) 'new file name = original number + i + the file extension
    fs.CopyFile OriginalPath, DestinationFolderPath & "\" & DestName
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help....The reference would be FileSystemObject under Tools -> References?

Comment: Under tools, references there will be an option called Microsoft Scripting Runtime - tick that one.

Comment: Rich the - 4 means what is this occasion? is it taking the length of OrigName - 4? Cheers

Comment: It's removing the file extension (.pdf) so that the number appears before the extension not after

Comment: I am still having trouble, for a reference 12345 I am getting the increased numbers in front of the 12345 like 123451, 123452 and so on, how can I remove the last digit and increment by 1? Thanks

Comment: Ah, I see. Are you file names always numeric? Like 12345.pdf?

Comment: Thanks so much Rich, it works now perfectly I only had to change the CInt to CLng as my refs can have more than 4 digits. thanks so much.